# Service Worker registration failed - Uncaught ReferenceError: export is not defined

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, tensorflow.js, parcel

I am trying to develop a chrome extension that is using a tensorflow model in the service worker. It gets bundled by parcel.
The extension works without any issues when I use an HMR server. However, after building the extension and trying to add it to Chrome, an error is thrown: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $379e4f2c7c8c5f6b$exports is not defined` which leads to `Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15`.

Many solutions propose to remove `"type": "module"`, to use ES6, or to define a global export variable in the html script. However, they don't work for various reasons.
Then, I tried to narrow down the problem based on answers that proposed it being an issue with code in the service worker.
I realized that the issue is connected to the imports. Without any, both errors disappear and the service-worker works. When **only** using the universal-sentence-encoder import, it lets me install the extension, but throws the ReferenceError upon interacting with the extension.

```
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu/dist/index.js';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl/dist/index.js';

import * as use from '@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder/dist/index.js';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/index.js';
```

I felt that I was importing the modules correctly, especially since this works with the HMR server, but it appears that I don't?
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your help!

In case the issue is connected to something else, I append the json files.

---

**manifest:**

```
...,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.ts",
        "type": "module"
    },
...
```

**tsconfig:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "es2022",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

**package**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder": "^1.3.3",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.6.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^3.6.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^3.6.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu": "^3.6.0",
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.6.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@parcel/config-webextension": "^2.8.3",
        "@types/chrome": "^0.0.238",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.60.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.60.0",
        "buffer": "^5.5.0",
        "eslint": "^8.43.0",
        "parcel": "^2.8.3",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "typescript": "5.1.6"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "copy-img": "if not exist \"dist/images\" mkdir \"dist/images\" && copy images \"dist/images\"",
        "start": "yarn copy-img && parcel watch manifest.json --host localhost",
        "build": "yarn copy-img && parcel build manifest.json"
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The browser can't run typescript so make sure your final manifest.json specifies the final js file. 2) Service worker can't use dynamic imports directly ([more info](/a/66408379)), so if your HMR implementation doesn't account for that it'll fail.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 1) yes, parcel takes care of that. 2) I stumbled upon your answer, but didn't think too much of it because of paragraph 0 (my imports are npm packages). I guessed using parcel should be enough. I will try "importScripts" and come back when I know if that works.
Just to clarify, the HMR works without issues using that exact code, it's the built package that fails :)

Comment: I now tried to import the USE (Universal Sentence Encoder) with importScripts(), but parcel throws the error `@parcel/transformer-js: importScripts() is not supported in module workers`. Also, the exports of the USE-index.js do not get available and trying to create an USE object creates a static import of it automatically.
The attempt to remove "type": "module" from the manifest thus leads to multiple issues, where 1) "type": "module" is needed, and 2) a fully qualified URL for importScripts would be necessary.
I feel like that this is a dead end. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some more, I decided to try webpack instead of parcel.
So in my case here, webpack was the solution.
However, I don't exactly know why this is the case.